# What does 'contravariance' on AbstractRecoilValue<T> mean in Recoil source type declarations?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, contravariance, recoiljs

I stumbled upon this part of typescript/index.d.ts in Recoil source:

```
export class AbstractRecoilValue<T> {
    __tag: [T];
    __cTag: (t: T) => void; // for contravariance

    key: NodeKey;
    constructor(newKey: NodeKey);
}
```

How does `__cTag` serve as a discriminator for contravariance here?

Here is whole context: [Github](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/pull/292/commits/5c8c5ab750655936493a5c0ef28d7b5e86f5d857#diff-2d042e5f33a7b3f604ddfc171a9cd4066c19952ee99f53f93bf54c411ecfa880R158)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think "for contravariance" should probably say "to prevent covariance" instead, but I'll explain what's going on in any case.  Let's say you have a type function `type F<T> = ...`.  If you have two types `A` and `B` where `B extends A`, like

```
interface A { a: string }
interface B extends A { b: number }

declare let a: A;
declare let b: B;
a = b; // okay
b = a; // error
```

what, if anything, can you say about the relationship between `F<A>` and `F<B>`?  There are two interesting cases to consider:

**`F<T>` is covariant in `T`**: whenever `B extends A`, then `F<B> extends F<A>`.  Since widening `T` will widen `F<T>` and narrowing `T` will narrow `F<T>`, you can say that `F<T>` *varies together* with `T`.  It "co-varies", or is covariant.  Function types are covariant in their return types.  In TypeScript, object types are considered to be covariant in their property types (even though this is [unsound when writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850736/2887218), it is useful).  `Array<T>` is covariant in `T` (even though this is [unsound when writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60922930/2887218), it is useful). And so `[T]` is covariant in `T`.

**`F<T>` is contravariant in `T`**: whenever `B extends A`, then `F<A> extends F<B>`.  Since widening `T` will narrow `F<T>` and narrowing `T` will widen `F<T>`, you can say that `F<T>` *varies opposite to* `T`.  It "counter-varies", or is contravariant.  Function types (with [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option enabled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)) are contravariant in their parameter types.  So `(t: T) => void` is contravariant in `T`.  In TypeScript, object types are also considered to be contravariant in their property key types.

In the above examples, when we say "`F<T>` is covariant in `T`" we also mean that it is *not* contravariant.  And vice versa; when we say "`F<T>` is contravariant in `T`" we also mean that it is *not* covariant.  So `[T]` is covariant (but not contravariant) in `T`, and `(t: T) => void` is contravariant (but not covariant) in `T`.  But we can consider this case too:

**`F<T>` is bivariant in T**: `F<T>` is both covariant and contravariant in `T`.  In a fully sound type system this would not happen unless `F<T>` did not depend on `T` at all.  But in TypeScript, [*method* types (or all function types with `--strictFunctionTypes` disabled) are considered bivariant in their parameter types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance).  Another situation of unsound-but-useful.

And finally:

**`F<T>` is invariant in `T`**: `F<T>` is neither covariant nor contravariant in `T`.  There's no simple relationship between `F<A>` and `F<B>` when `B extends A`.  This tends to be the most common situation.  Covariance and contravariance are "fragile" in the sense then if you compose covariant and contravariant types you tend to get invariant types.  This is what happens when you combine `[T]` and `(t: T) => void` in the `AbstractRecoilValue<T>` definition.  The `_tag` property is covariant (but not contravariant) in `T`, and the `_cTag` property is contravariant (but not covariant) in `T`.  By putting them together, `AbstractRecoilValue<T>` is invariant in `T`.

---

So presumably `_cTag` was added so that `AbstractRecoilValue<T>` would be invariant in `T` and not covariant in `T`.  You can see the difference in behavior if you comment it out:

```
declare class AbstractRecoilValue<T> {
  __tag: [T];
  // __cTag: (t: T) => void; // for contravariance
  key: NodeKey;
  constructor(newKey: NodeKey);
}

declare let arvA: AbstractRecoilValue<A>;
declare let arvB: AbstractRecoilValue<B>;

arvA = arvB; // okay
arvB = arvA; // error!
```

You can see that `AbstractRecoilValue<B>` is assignable to `AbstractRecoilValue<A>`, but not vice versa.  So `AbstractRecoilValue<T>` is covariant in `T`.  But if we restore `__cTag`:

```
declare class AbstractRecoilValue<T> {
  __tag: [T];
  __cTag: (t: T) => void; // for contravariance
  key: NodeKey;
  constructor(newKey: NodeKey);
}

declare let arvA: AbstractRecoilValue<A>;
declare let arvB: AbstractRecoilValue<B>;

arvA = arvB; // error!
arvB = arvA; // error!
```

then neither assignment is acceptable, and so `AbstractRecoilValue<T>` is invariant in `T`.

---

If you want to know *why* such a restriction was placed on `AbstractRecoilValue<T>`, I can't answer that, since I'm not sure what it's used for... that seems to be out of scope for the question as asked, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=26#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgJbAAuEATgGYLIByA9gCYQDSEAnnkjJYzABcSEMG4BffISShIsOkgDCAV0qUI5PFKJFW8DCHVJ9IKFCQBBAEZQylBGQBKEeI2IYAapmUQAPABUAPi0dHQB9MLIQAHNhAG1-AF0AbmlQiPh-GOEACjJhfwBKJABeYIA3N2ZkpAB6WqRqRkpjRnJ7csNiUURtUKQAay5hJlYOTlT+1uBbSmV4Mmac4AgAd3GRlnYuQsmdSTSScipaREseEGFZ0mikSVDSChoFACEkCAAPCmBmcwseKzCYDKMBWKh3Pq6FwGIwYCBkETCCx7KEmWHwpCApAvFEiUqYmr1JCMAYgTiHKz4kCEhpUfiUSFIPQw5BwhGGcoWJE2OwOZyudxeDA+XwWQK45mGVkYjkvbmzPkuNyebx+F7ixkc-4lESUco4uq0tTNACEh1lVL1yMN72NlDN0gORFk0DgZwA6sQyAALRjKMiKKK3AiHSVGExmSw8+wLfnKoUioIhfoRIPxJK4ohEjJZWJIPIFYplJCVYjVG1NFqudogTqUbrAXpTIacTZjLiZ6azeaLSjLNYbJCjbacXaHJ06R4nBT-XCIpDXYC3e6T47PM5vT7fX7nOdY4Gg8ET1EspBs+fI0PQqVnjFYnHm-FWGnE0nk0KUnXUm105qMsPSuyVryrysZKoKqqihqoQAbeQH6iBMZOOBKrCmqGrmlalr6i+JJkph+rYdaRK-vafQHOIQA)